# Static Sidebar and Fluid content with header and footer

Tags: html, css

Hi I have been having a problem with coding my layout I want to have my sidebar stay the same with regardless of screen size, but I also need my content area to be fluid. The header stays at the top which is what I want the problem is the footer I need it to stay always at the bottom and the full width of the content area. If anyone can help it would be muchly appreciated.

Here is my code.

```css
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
}   

#content { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}   

#left { 
    width: 20%; 
    height: 100%; 
    float: left; 
    background-color: red; 
}   

#right { 
    float: left; 
    width: 80%; 
    height: 100%;  
    background-color: green;
} 

#right header { 
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

#right footer {
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>   
    <div id='left'>Testing</div>   
    <div id='right'>
        <header>TITLE</header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>lorem ipsum and the like.</p>
        </div> 
        <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you should do :

- First, replace the `float:left;` with `display: table-cell;` for your `#left` and `#right` selectors.
- Then, use `display: table;` for your `#content` selector.
- Then, remove the `width: 80%;` of your `#right` and `#right footer` selectors
- Add `right : 0;` to your `#right footer` selector
- Finally, set the `left` of your footer and the `width` of your sidebar to the same fixed with and you're there.

The beauty of this approach, is that it also works on IE8 and other browsers that do not have support for `calc()`.

### A demo :

```css
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
}   

#content { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}   

#left { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%; 
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red; 
}   

#right { 
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;  
    background-color: green;
} 

#right header { 
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

#right footer {
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right : 0;
    left : 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>   
    <div id='left'>Testing</div>   
    <div id='right'>
        <header>TITLE</header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>lorem ipsum and the like.</p>
        </div> 
        <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7azqbymk/).

Comment: @dippas : I've been using this technique for years. Why shouldn't I do it like this, in your opinion?! Also, do you know an alternative approach that also works in older browsers?

Comment: yup I do, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7azqbymk/), just using `table/table-cell` based on your fiddle, made it very quickly

Comment: @dippas : Thanks for the suggestions. I have to agree with you that is actually a better approach. I should really start using  `display : table` and `display : table-cell` more often. Anyway, I just updated my answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your time and help! Now I can get moving a little more on this project can't thank you enough.

Comment: @K-Dawg you are accepting an answer made by me which other user used instead the answer I gave you? just wondering...

Comment: @dippas : The accepted answer is more or less a collaboration between both of us, so I guess credit should go to both of us... I could ask you, however, why you chose to help me improve my answer instead of improve your own answer. In its current state, your answer does come off as less elegant to me, which strikes me as odd, considering your insight offered in my question does illustrate an eye for elegant code.

Comment: @JohnSlegers I gave you an answer based on your question? *Also, do you know an alternative approach that also works in older browsers?*, and you used my answer to update yours, just saying, no problem :)

Comment: @dippas : Look... Your improvements on my answer are a better approach than BOTH my initial answer AND your own answer. If you have a problem with my improving my answer based on your suggestions, I don't understand why you didn't just improve your own answer. Nevertheless, I wish I could share any rep given for this answer with you, but I can't. I'm afraid all I can do, here, is give you an +1 on your own answer, and a random other answer (I guess your top answer makes most sense).

Comment: No problems @JohnSlegers, i'm fine really! I upvoted yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inline-block` over `float:left` to avoid problems with `clear`ings, but when using `inline-block` better use `vh` over `%` to fill the viewport.

And to have a fixed sidebar, just give it a fixed `width` and use `calc` to calculate the remaining space.

you can do something like this:

#### Snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#content {
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 0; /* fix inline-block gap */ 
}
#content > div {
  font-size: 16px; /* revert font-size 0 */
}
#left {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100vw - 150px);
  height: 100vh;
  background: green
}
#right header {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
#right footer {
  background: brown;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 150px);
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <div id='left'>Testing</div>
  <div id='right'>
    <header>TITLE</header>
    <div class="content">
      <p>lorem ipsum and the like.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```